# Can you send an sms to an app regardless of which country you reside?

Tags: android, sms, telephony, provider

I've ran across a topic that discusses how you could create an app that allows you to send an sms to the application and receive them from it. My question is simply the following:

Can someone send an sms to that app regardless of where they live or are there any limitations in terms of service provider etc?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "send an sms to the application" since SMS are inherently sent to phone numbers/devices, not applications.

Comment: You send SMS only to numbers, not to apps

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are going to have to use Google Cloud Messaging to accomplish this, seen [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be after push notifications rather than an SMS. Amazon's [Simple Notification Service (SNS)](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) allows you to send push notifications as wells as SMSs though and has an Android SDK.

In either scenario you'd be able to send SMSs or push notifications to any device regardless of its location.